# How to visualise kmeans clustercenters

Tags: clustering, k-means, spark-mllib

Asking here as I can't find a tutorial anywhere, and am new to this topic.

I've run a kmeans algorithm in spark Scala on some data, and have a prediction object that contains clusterCenters, how can I use the clusterCenters object to create a graph?

Do I pass it in to R/Python then call functions on it?

These are my cluster centers:

```
[0.001236304489457427,0.0024935772814388586,1.8829616518250576E-4,0.006765576057860339,0.008464243776401714,0.008482699067581286,0.003923951726928943,0.0017809196541664846,0.012008194418141297,1.652114007747148E-4,0.007931301191862455,0.897129466488848,0.04943025828135285,1.7729071763899337E-4,0.010365545946959117,3.9604072763395234E-4,0.0031781437319335433,0.006359661882497008,7.39793633100585E-4,3.776029537948685E-5,0.0025824160666782555,4.5913487577603894E-5,0.005226037608622276,1.943442603683635E-4,0.0,9.243952333244974E-6,0.0,1.273037776218916E-4,1.3755245441439406E-6,6.848864547146916E-4,4.867713295077438E-6,0.0,0.0,5.876309128398988E-4,1.8088666682073905E-6,0.0017441043601686287,2.2670557004308262E-5,0.0021223274156146102,6.826178794661345E-5,5.1139902159501136E-5,0.0,0.9832667172286259,0.00251858020200595,0.008554941592236756,3.979549185058153E-5]
[0.002209638027390689,0.0013386181787457996,1.2751155045160882E-4,0.005165161664083505,0.016878184214240508,0.035531137686639735,0.0026319354787715057,0.001904546114007198,0.02629624268359568,5.003564904065877E-4,0.011307737776825337,0.8470169836874836,0.04909194644734185,7.08445520608596E-5,5.590338532753816E-4,1.287326006306981E-4,0.993442596921538,0.003040600658071089,1.8351662333672135E-4,1.1455256673159663E-5,5.719977280088873E-4,4.360014169433171E-6,0.0019868617922283124,6.859933127831683E-4,0.0,2.5580598381234522E-5,0.0,2.1163443860506268E-4,3.216174226628822E-5,6.197141464460653E-4,7.779234356614491E-5,0.0,0.0,6.016755159633969E-4,5.05372538458266E-5,0.004039562619464969,6.123536015252999E-4,0.007431265839694599,0.0014732204075933338,1.3688285330477534E-4,0.0,0.8742347848645152,0.09630918468755345,0.012393882298817611,0.0010637734756526202]
[0.009037301716134013,6.338410962864746E-4,6.166156461501015E-5,9.852082126504476E-4,0.027340509872878355,0.001856228176521537,5.255922074207073E-4,3.186722597640989E-4,0.9420054110959097,5.617044725800985E-5,8.326066251644742E-4,0.012750521110921922,0.0035962756144669876,2.6986542164511183E-4,0.0014002535963311647,1.5394910625213568E-4,0.0045229387075021886,0.016841632854645783,0.0010473439059850316,8.418539207726942E-6,0.03866401070500873,2.2807351419294167E-5,0.004637212163795187,8.852458473246977E-4,0.0,1.791846946319928E-5,0.0,3.840231720658566E-5,7.813527439976405E-6,2.305368739936695E-4,8.712161978116347E-6,0.0,0.0,2.4955163588568177E-4,5.119377619938468E-6,5.005784878825603E-4,1.742769915165039E-4,0.43706624673154654,0.011443265919683747,9.685020543522845E-5,0.0,0.012780371224842619,0.0011880511794807908,0.0019463099317691135,4.245262648071365E-4]
[0.0038979918300486986,0.004234886866225224,5.7674195055966825E-5,0.007823895333964303,0.018629524929764406,0.6436560581145097,0.0026882287694659475,0.0017515048748683335,0.014669545383153093,8.090381737035173E-4,0.0277977700523551,0.23575208210315254,0.03823179937373047,2.386851394251262E-4,4.8367457839874737E-4,3.504052196392817E-4,0.9725686099774334,0.007643793389377598,0.0041373329485963105,4.88582838934377E-5,3.941863504270558E-4,2.6717093929247743E-5,0.0031465291443155195,0.004622700128514986,0.0,2.995597928459797E-4,0.0,3.900220037087221E-4,1.1111145426099754E-4,0.0010176618725598846,1.7296839626459345E-4,8.101608463969063E-8,0.0,0.0011134986514986758,1.446384256050647E-4,0.012353553769999122,0.002452983459017941,0.017672875569757888,0.005201058667079603,4.168388696470924E-4,0.0,0.7538605599614031,0.1709318236900782,0.026031405105827594,0.0032066591658375145]
[0.01600848720412885,0.01031938883109214,0.0012738804791494103,0.020671349638853007,0.020754345056184988,0.761910208624425,0.010203138154698648,0.004654128945349225,0.022528184227801056,7.722061481150032E-4,0.00837938733841898,0.0869832525575325,0.03554204279425817,9.389095778188699E-4,0.0010736869758782043,6.260678407590004E-4,0.8172238183792072,0.012439343103133231,0.010337996069877118,7.07917428866536E-5,8.594749429346958E-4,5.499634746951286E-5,0.0060465003674033575,0.046299258879935086,0.0,0.001532956090287073,0.0,0.0013845564645270667,5.778501223367275E-4,0.00669542885762704,6.99191908673402E-4,9.729282630026527E-8,0.0,0.007626874416786177,8.425408912602915E-4,0.026356931874771207,0.007767921226777793,0.09563912932430302,0.044223091852546824,0.003928911574366478,0.0,0.11704220139417704,0.16975999113320217,0.10216722254434471,0.013589430398517083]
[0.005397197980986729,0.009556441258613088,0.0036940458939813377,0.03432486736680606,0.019345909926592637,0.0021188861683324625,0.018947193550742675,0.008348834114799553,0.002726043874393314,1.8643303595854773E-4,7.963662711541098E-4,0.8866951003126259,0.007862680245008179,1.4101209764985994E-4,0.002596936842619598,2.4631792211438026E-4,5.672186239195572E-4,5.657079643073396E-4,2.4141194971035763E-4,1.8497860712817024E-5,5.207647974123866E-4,2.1486593164028848E-5,0.002385794587484674,0.0011153761619638613,0.0,4.6484467790734714E-5,0.0,3.4815562836638887E-4,2.1565322054211716E-5,0.006217432655189877,1.7813183189653764E-5,0.0,0.0,0.004466361777974677,1.0654494773452066E-5,0.0031527587956967796,5.950291603455552E-4,0.0021136492703029437,3.8249021785384323E-4,3.279230091580942E-4,0.0,0.002941262849024523,3.155356422411563E-4,0.008439069958859414,8.880147923896979E-5]
[0.0013214410388267671,6.977312137806204E-4,2.56430336938021E-4,0.003368655043380258,0.004485555041737335,0.009446840061150081,0.008237737728285476,0.0013482697891785385,0.006615338572021724,7.126832217322566E-5,0.0025058492109347815,0.0661948102712231,0.8954500733703817,2.002109741712575E-4,0.0036778406234721575,2.061950606173467E-4,0.11472118706672627,0.017533857108032062,5.362183849848126E-4,4.4183532264277263E-5,0.002054242854520748,5.340802883323861E-5,0.0029626662937231383,0.001788434969455903,0.0,5.439733858172388E-5,0.0,4.4466501373049153E-4,2.5659067057176173E-5,0.0012727159911557857,2.765244319008673E-5,0.0,0.0,0.0050986645354454225,4.939654329984241E-5,0.0045458041171167925,2.6609186724883436E-4,0.0060479981710160734,9.916558609959125E-4,0.001186894753982496,0.0,0.08558098005570186,0.002762474611727729,0.30486449286857864,0.012069332353973726]
[0.01353955889015213,0.0028746585750482005,1.2196709726571591E-4,0.005175328937842391,0.023842466944178898,0.01134625888578699,0.0021001327572411337,9.639763692349349E-4,0.8514776554445559,2.94580532738434E-4,0.005440483395800154,0.0615079936023691,0.021314938567785695,3.187713742257356E-4,0.0010056618647318629,1.463125948788484E-4,0.9897248440253738,0.002021139684360548,4.711347612882951E-4,5.188560048578653E-6,0.005433282597524428,1.039218028044936E-6,8.726253195386498E-4,0.006993301047901191,0.0,8.289676102466511E-5,0.0,1.8466508935668455E-4,5.4974095565859235E-5,9.565691024969483E-4,1.505885842898953E-4,0.0,0.0,9.152550033575047E-4,7.039151215513156E-5,0.0023764057875899757,5.612399562588812E-4,0.6009632714986249,0.06068344992909765,5.88627370200846E-4,0.0,0.05903105526066141,0.009915615252712971,0.009601158723053074,6.780973728533626E-4]
[0.004699564576413924,0.0067469676020055535,5.952320014157358E-4,0.0077340740448138675,0.02473177777616151,0.07782365343480056,0.004895894368335355,0.003919522222201566,0.02322373601851672,0.0013151786624247149,0.008542630571974966,0.7909015488143796,0.04487021990655491,4.669903884440107E-4,7.98211344272475E-4,3.136002091196845E-4,0.9885421246774572,0.004816812895710735,0.0015541198992170746,4.434357667662471E-5,4.3692349791411996E-4,1.5896655295296218E-5,0.0030109768558875317,0.009164731789150034,0.0,5.289982705172572E-4,0.0,9.968417825408445E-4,4.516804948613364E-4,0.002501741270381679,4.881370103498913E-4,7.2578703365499824E-9,0.0,0.004123089366494392,4.4878927606074425E-4,0.01325319853379619,0.004518716430638884,0.02500008734991295,0.013866943898930034,0.003184750037259434,0.0,0.19782525369277115,0.2535177431276766,0.046173593178246895,0.006320973768730514]
[0.005822042625534463,0.007631794891253944,2.2214430834779152E-4,0.007190931856094663,0.028801304681821762,0.24528647839230527,0.0038463740498840566,0.004206932713618265,0.04751231217621488,0.0012494544142828124,0.01172306022304427,0.5911101324124582,0.04539703725514016,0.002965323421281445,9.641755141860535E-4,7.782624300270701E-4,0.17143313135519894,0.59236118927212,0.0038258806424700093,5.3958416107999003E-5,5.902272114286947E-4,5.884911028355625E-4,0.20590298900090953,0.004360771288550716,0.0,2.2135175529675293E-4,0.0,1.819067549067393E-4,1.8548292316049222E-4,8.199416882946424E-4,1.6521783624214853E-4,0.0,0.0,0.0014272151003024858,5.86547305024247E-4,0.004675615260397958,0.006105552562151834,0.019311709862109463,0.019351827463925372,4.399866794388066E-4,0.0,0.18112002878277467,0.6548843459041614,0.014764494282143633,0.03149656225864]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data were low dimensional, then you would just plot them as with any plot.

Essentially, you can always visualize the cluster centers just as you visualize your input data.

But how do you visualize very high dimensional data? Probably not at all; and certainly not with a "library" method. Instead, *you* need to use your data knowledge to visualize the important aspects of it.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32008994/17289869) previously answered. I was able to plot both clusters and raw data using the code. This uses python seaborn and sklearn, but you can probably find a way to plot your own data manually by reworking the functions.

Here is a sample of how it would look for an example (4 features, n=122, k=4)
[image]